# sort by number & character in reverse?

Tags: bash, sort

I have a list of files like:

```
100119329_d01.png
100119329_d08.png
100119329_d02.png
100119329_d05.png
100119329_d03.png
100119329_d04.png
100119329_d07.png
100119329_f02.png
100119329_f01.png
```

I want to sort by numbers and then by the preceding character in reverse to get the following output:

```
100119329_f01.png
100119329_f02.png
100119329_d01.png
100119329_d02.png
100119329_d03.png
100119329_d04.png
100119329_d05.png
100119329_d07.png
100119329_d08.png
```

I've tried:

```
cat <file> |sort -k1.11r -k1.12,1.13n
```

but only one of the arguments work at a time. So I can only sort by number or by reversed character.
How can I get both to work at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse sorting only for the 11th char, e.g.

```
sort -k1.11,1.11r -k1.12,1.13n infile
```

though in this case (numbers are zero-padded) you could simply run

```
sort -k1.11,1.11r infile
```

Comment: They want the letter in reverse, but number forward, so you need two keys in any case.

Answer (score 1):

If the aim is to process those files in that order afterwards, with zsh, that sorting could be done using glob qualifiers:

```
$ print -rC1 -- *_?[0-9][0-9].png(Oe['REPLY=$REPLY[-7]$((200-REPLY[-6,-5]))'])
100119329_f01.png
100119329_f02.png
100119329_d01.png
100119329_d02.png
100119329_d03.png
100119329_d04.png
100119329_d05.png
100119329_d07.png
100119329_d08.png
```

Were we sort in reverse (captial `O`) based on the result of the `e`valuation of some code that defines the sort key as *the-letter* followed 200 - *the-number*. So the key for `100119329_f01.png` is `f199` and the key for `100119329_a99.png` is `a101`.

To do anything else with those files:

```
for file ( *_?[0-9][0-9].png(Oe['REPLY=$REPLY[-7]$((200-REPLY[-6,-5]))']) )
  anything-else-with -- $file
```

for instance.